# Parameterizing the upper hemisphere of a sphere with an upward pointing normal

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

Can someone explain how to do this?

area we're dealing with:

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2, z \geq 0$

I'm aware that the answer is:

$x = a \sin(\phi) \cos(\theta)$

$y = a \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta)$

$z = a \cos(\phi)$

I'm just not quite sure how to get there.

Thanks!

Comment: You're aware of spherical coordinates? Anyway, here's an idea: imagine a segment of length $a$ above the x-y plane, and note the angles it makes with the z-axis, and the angle made by its "shadow" in the x-y plane and the x-axis.

Comment: I was able to find the answer, I just want to know why that is the answer, if that makes sense.

Comment: $z\geq 0$ obviously leads to the condition $\phi\leq\pi/2$. Together with the usual restriction on the parameters of spherical coordinates, you get $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $\phi \in [0,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, $\theta$ represents longitude on the (hemi-)sphere, and $\phi$ represents co-latitude.  If you let $a$ vary, then it would describe altitude.

To see that these coordinates actually describe the hemisphere is straightfoward: all you have to do is check that
$$\begin{align*}
x & = a \sin \phi \cos \theta \\
y &= a \sin \phi \sin \theta \\
z &= a \cos \phi
\end{align*}$$
actually satisfy $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$.

---

But how would one actually *derive* these coordinates?  Essentially, it works the same as in 2-dimensional polar coordinates: draw the right triangle and use "soh cah toa."

So which right triangle do we draw?  Let $O$ denote the origin, let $P = (x,y,z)$ denote the point on the (hemi-)sphere in question, and let $Q = (x,y,0)$ denote the projection of $P$ directly down onto the $xy$-plane.  Look at the triangle $\Delta OPQ$.  Mathworld's page on [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) has an illustration of this.

The height of this triangle (side $PQ$) has length $z$, the base (side $OQ$) has length $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and the hypotenuse (side $OP$) is the radius of the sphere $a$.  Then by "soh cah toa,"
$$\begin{align*}
r &= a \sin \phi \\
z &= a \cos\phi.
\end{align*}$$
Now we examine the point $Q$, and use 2-dimensional polar coordinates.  Since the length of $OQ$ is $r = a\sin\phi$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
x &= (a \sin \phi)\cos \theta \\
y &= (a \sin\phi)\sin\theta,
\end{align*}$$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: In the actual setup of conventional spherical coordinates, $\phi$ is actually co-latitude, the complement of the latitude. Some care is needed in comparing results in the literature, since some references use $\theta$ for the co-latitude and $\phi$ for the longitude.

Comment: True.  Fixed. (character limit)